# Passing objects to multiple services

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a need to run multiple WCF services at the same time, from a single windows service. Each WCF service is basically the same, but has one object specific to that instance. So with the following service class:

```
public class MyService : IMyContract
{
    public MyType MyObject { get; set; }

    public MyService(MyType myObject)
    {
        this.MyObject = myObject;
    }
    // more here...
}
```

I hoped I would be able to do something like this:

```
MyType o1 = new MyType();
MyService s1 = new MyService(o1);
ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(s1, anEndpointAddress);
MyType o2 = new MyType();
MyService s2 = new MyService(s2);
ServiceHost host2 = new ServiceHost(s2, anEndpointAddress);
```

The problem is, that if you use the ServiceHost constructor that takes an object as its first argument, that object needs to be a singletonInstance, but I need multiple instances.

On the other hand, if I use the constructor which takes a type as its first argument (`ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), endpointAddress);`), I don't know how I can set MyObject to a suitable value.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks, regards, Miel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways - way 2 will be preferred approach.

1. Create multiple classes that simply inherits from your service class. For example,

   ```
   public class MyService1 : MyService { 
   ... // put a constructor that accepts your object 
   }
   public class MyService2 : MyService { ...  }

   ...
   ```

And now host as

```
MyType o1 = new MyType();
MyService s1 = new MyService1(o1);
ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(s1, anEndpointAddress);
MyType o2 = new MyType();
MyService s2 = new MyService2(s2);
ServiceHost host2 = new ServiceHost(s2, anEndpointAddress);
```

If you don;t want singleton then you need to modify these classes such as

```
 public class MyService1 : MyService
{
   public MyService1() : base(new MyType()) { }
}
```

and then use another service host constructor

```
ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService1), anEndpointAddress);
```

**2. I would prefer this approach.** Service implementation will not have instance variable holding MyObject. Write custom ServiceHost class such as

```
public class MyServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public MyType MyObject { get; private set; }

   public MyServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses, MyType myObject) 
     :base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
   {
     this.MyObject = myObject;
   }
}
```

Now, host your service on multiple endpoint addresses using

```
MyType o1 = new MyType();
ServiceHost host1 = new MyServiceHost(typeof(MyService, anEndpointAddress, o1);
```

In service methods, use `OperationContext.Current.Host` to get servicehost and from hostm you can get your object.

Comment: Nr 2 is the one, indeed. The first only allows for a fixed number of services, which isn't flexible enough. I didn't know about OperationContext.Current.Host. And that's exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to plug-in your own `ServiceHost`.

First create your custom ServiceHost by inheriting it and implement your custom loading there.
Then create a behaviour by implementing  `IServiceBehavior` and modify `ChannelDispatchers` to set your own ServiceHost.

Have a look here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx